# iproute2 and NetworkManager on Ubuntu15.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, ip

#### Is there a way to "properly" configure a default route using the `iproute2` suite of tools on an Ubuntu system?

My desktop/server is connected via ethernet to a **switch**; when the system boots and network comes up the system "gets confused" as there are other systems *along with* the gateway that are connected to the same switch.  The result is that the Ubuntu 15.04 system fails to connect to the external network.

```
# ip route show
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link metric 100
...
```

Once I issue

```
# ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
```

I see something about `whoopsie` in the journal messages and I have network conectivity!

```
# ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link metric 100
...
```

Now, **how do I make this persistent** on this system without, for lack of a better term, hard-coding it in the `/etc/network/` subdirectories? Using NetworkManager and its nmcli tool there doesn't seem to be a way for me to assign the connection a Gateway unless I turn off DHCP entirely! Is this a shortcoming within NetworkManager or Ubuntu or iproute2?

I see `/etc/iproute2` directory; though, there seems to be no indication in the man-pages on how to make configuration changes persistent.  Searching through the StackExchange network of relevant Q&A sites I've come across different suggestions that don't really outline a canonical way of achieving this.  <s>Maybe DHCP *does* need to be disabled for this in NetworkManager, I'm not sure.</s>

#### systemd

For the time being, I'm adding the line to `/etc/rc.local`.  However, that fails during bootup, since I'm assuming it gets executed *before* network is ready.

```
# systemctl status -l rc-local.service
...
...rc.local[1396]: RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
...
```

Restarting the service *after* system is up resolves the failure.  Going forward with `systemd`, AFAIK, the idea is to stop using/supporting that script.  Maybe user-level services should be used now?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by adding below line in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
post-up route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

or

```
post-up route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

add this at below side of interface definition like

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.50
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        post-up route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

or

using `iproute2` you can do bellow steps:
open file `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and add `1      rt2` at the end it will look like :

```
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
# local
#1  inr.ruhep
 1      rt2
```

and open `/etc/network/interfaces` file and add

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.50
netmask 255.255.255.0
post-up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.50 table rt2
post-up ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table rt2
post-up ip rule add from 192.168.1.1 table rt2
post-up ip rule add to 192.168.1.1 table rt2
```

if you are using multiple interface then you can define static routing for all interface.
i hope it will help.

Comment: what happens to other interfaces then? For that matter, what happens when the link/network changes? That's the "hard-coded" way I was trying to avoid.  At least with the `rc-local.service` there is one central location to check and make changes.

Comment: are you using sttatic ip or dhcp ? .

Comment: DHCP, but ethernet is connected to LAN switch, not to router.  Gateway is connected to LAN switch also.  I could make a static address on Gateway side, but that's not the point.

Comment: if you are using multiple interface then you can do static routing for all instead of default gateway.  same way you can add this line to all interface